# Visual c++ 6.0 Application size bigger than visual studio 2010 application size

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe, antivirus

I am currently editing a c++ application (only using plain api ),When i compiled it with 2010 (release configration )the size was 28 kb but when i did this with vc++ 6 it was 42 kb.

why is this

I cant use 2010 version for release because my bit defender says its a virus (my software is a self extracting exe uses lzma compresssion , i think thats why bitdefender says it is a virus , but ok with vc++ 6 )

also : bit defender not says after building the exe ; when i add any file to exe using `copy /b` using cmd it says its a virus ; again no problem with v6

Comment: Have you checked that the compiler settings are exactly the same when you compile with either of them?

Comment: The compiler has evolved a bit over the last 14 years...

Comment: @Lagerbaer i don't know that there a much settings in v6.00 like in 2010

Comment: Well, there are always certain optimization options you can use (or not): You can have the compiler optimize for speed or for code size. For example, loop unrolling is good for speed and bad for size, same for function inlining, etc. etc.

Comment: You finally upgraded your compiler, good.  Now you probably should update your virus scanner tool as well.  Or dump self-extraction, it is pretty pointless when you can get a one terabyte disk for well less than a hundred bucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different file sizes after compilation might be because the newer VisualStudio uses newer c-runtimes which add some runtime-checks to the code that weren't existing at VS 6 times.

Dont't know about the virus thing - maybe you have different output paths with the one from VS 2010 being in a directory watched by BitDefender?